# Stacked column in highchart(stockchart) scrollbar

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, stacked-chart

In stockchart present in highchart, is it possible to show scrollbar chart same as the main chart.

existing: [image: chart created by me]
required: [image: Required chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show additional series in navigator by using `showInNavigator` property and enable `stacking` for the series in navigator.

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    showInNavigator: true
  }
},
series: [{
  data: [...]
}, {
  data: [...]
}, {
  data: [...]
}],
navigator: {
  series: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    type: 'column'
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4951/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.column.showInNavigator

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.series